# Работа трёх потоков с двумя файлами

Tags: python, многопоточность

У меня есть два txt файла, назовём их "text1.txt" и "text2.txt", также у меня есть три потока и семафор из пакета threaing:

1. Первый поток записывает в *text1.txt* текст
2. Второй поток записывает текст в *text2.txt*
3. Третий поток пытается читать "txt" файлы

Проблема в том, что я не понимаю, как "объединить" работу всех трёх потоков под строгим руководством семафора.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Вот пример чтения и записи в 2 файла 3 потоками:

```
import threading
import time


class SharedFile:
    def __init__(self, filename):
        self.filename = filename
        self.sem = threading.Semaphore()

    def writefile(self, text):
        self.sem.acquire()

        print('Запись в файл ' + self.filename)
        f = open(self.filename, 'a')
        f.write(text)
        f.close()

        self.sem.release()

    def readfile(self):
        self.sem.acquire()

        print('Чтение файла ' + self.filename)
        f = open(self.filename, 'r')
        text = f.read()
        f.close()

        self.sem.release()
        return text


class WriteThread(threading.Thread):
    def __init__(self, file):
        super().__init__()
        self.file = file

    def run(self):
        while True:
            self.file.writefile('newLine\n')
            time.sleep(0.05)


class ReadThread(threading.Thread):
    def __init__(self, file1, file2):
        super().__init__()
        self.file1 = file1
        self.file2 = file2

    def run(self):
        while True:
            self.file1.readfile()
            self.file2.readfile()
            time.sleep(0.05)


fileT1 = SharedFile('1.txt')
fileT2 = SharedFile('2.txt')

WriteThread(fileT1).start()
WriteThread(fileT2).start()
ReadThread(fileT1, fileT2).start()

while True:
    time.sleep(1)
```

Теперь о том как работает:
Есть класс SharedFile, который отвечает за чтение и запись одного файла, при этом возможна работа одновременно нескольких потоков с одним объектом, т.к. семафор (у каждого файла будет свой) не позволит разным потокам одновременно писать или читать из файла (в один и тот же момент времени только 1 из всех потоков будет иметь доступ к файлу)

Далее идут 2 класса для потоков - WriteThread (Записывает данные в переданный файл) и ReadThread(Читает данные из переданных файлов)

И в конце создаём 2 файла и 3 потока

```
fileT1 = SharedFile('1.txt')
fileT2 = SharedFile('2.txt')

WriteThread(fileT1).start()
WriteThread(fileT2).start()
ReadThread(fileT1, fileT2).start()

while True:
    time.sleep(1)
```

По умолчанию семафор будет доступен только 1 потоку, что можно увидеть по коду класса

```
class Semaphore:
...
    def __init__(self, value=1):
        if value < 0:
            raise ValueError("semaphore initial value must be >= 0")
        self._cond = Condition(Lock())
        self._value = value
...
```

При вызове функции def acquire(self, blocking=True, timeout=None) только 1-му потоку будет дан доступ, остальные будут ждать, пока семафор не освободится (значение value станет > 0):

```
def acquire(self, blocking=True, timeout=None):
...
    with self._cond:
        while self._value == 0:
            ...
            # Ожидание
            ...
            self._cond.wait(timeout)
        else:
            # Доступ
            self._value -= 1
            rc = True
    return rc
...
```

Comment: Спасибо большое